# Splitting Elements in a 2Dlist into sub-elements? Python 3

Tags: python

I'm a brand new programmer and started out with python as my first language.

```
for user in range (1):
    rowcol=input()
a=[]
a=rowcol.split(" ")
rowNum=int(a[0])
colNum=int(a[1])

board=[]    

for row_count in range(rowNum):
    row=[]
    row.append(input())
    board.append(row)
print(board)
```

the first input is "2 2" which determines the rows and columns 
the next input is "--" and "--" which inputs these characters in both rows

the array I have rn displays [['--'], ['--']]
I need it to display this [['-','-'], ['-','-']]

I don't know how to attempt splitting each element in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I achieved the result you desire by replacing this line

```
row.append(input())
```

with this one

```
row += [char for char in input()]
```

If you are not familiar with the syntax, please check out **[List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one-liner:

```
output = [list(y) for y in x for x in board]
```